# How do I stop Eclipse from continuously closing the editor?

Tags: eclipse

Every time I click out of the editor, on a toolbar item or to the file explorer, Eclipse auto-hides all my open projects and/or files to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyIh3.png). Then I have to reopen everything. It's super annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the file `workbench.xmi` in your workspace-folder under the path `.\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench`. This resets the workbench and the file is generated new.